# SOAP async/sync request

Tags: java, spring, soap, jms, spring-ws

My task is to develop async/sync responses using spring-ws. Im using JMS(ActiveMQ) for request processing and return `DefferedResult<?>`. The response from Endpoint should be following:
FOR ASYNC REQUEST

```
1.
  Client (Request)--> EndPoint(Server
  Client <--(Response) HTTP.202 Endpoint(Server)
2. Processing request via JMS
  Client(Endpoint) <--(Response) Endpoint
```

FOR SYNC REQUEST

```
1.
  Client (Request)--> EndPoint(Server)
  Client(Endpoint) <--(Response) Endpoint
```

P.S. If im trying to return `DefferedResult` in SYNC request case - it's not work

If im trying to use `ReplyTo:Client(Endpoint)` - it's not work

What's the best approach to solve my problem? Is there any examples?

Comment: What's not working exactly? Do you have to have the same endpoint for processing both sync and async requests (I'd say these are different endpoints).

Comment: yes it's different endpoint, it's defined in WSDL, with requered ReplyTo field its  async request otherwise sync. I suppose, like in REST, we can return DefferedResult and while JMS processing answer rest endpoint promote connection for responsing, in sync case, but in SOAP endpoint i don't know how it can be implemented, because we can't return DefferedResult as  @ResponsePayload.

Comment: And as for async responses, i hoped that spring-ws can return response in ReplyTo, but this is not so